# Why are three tags necessary for the IOB format? What problem would be caused if we used I and O tags exclusively?

Tags: parts-of-speech, nltk

I'm trying to understand how representing chunks works by facing this question :

> The IOB format categorizes tagged tokens as I , O , and B . Why are three tags necessary? What problem would be caused if we used I and O tags exclusively?
>   <sub>[ch7, Extracting Information from Text, 
> *Natural Language Understanding with Python*,S. Bird, E. Klein, and E. Loper](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/IT%20Various/natural_language_processing_with_python.pdf#page=309)</sub>

In IOB scheme,

> Each token is tagged with one of three special chunk tags, I (inside), O (outside), or B (begin). A token is tagged as B if it marks the beginning of a chunk. Subsequent tokens within the chunk are tagged I . All other tokens are tagged O .

I don't understand why would it be an issue to only have inside and outside tags, we would still have chunks which is the main purpose of this method, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blogpost on LingPipe](https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/) gives a fine overview over chunk encoding. It says explicitly over the IO encoding (that is IOB without B)

```
The simplest encoding is the IO encoding, which tags each token as either
being in (I_X) a particular type of named entity type X or in no entity
(O). This encoding is defective in that it can’t represent two entities
next to each other, because there’s no boundary tag.
```